# Is $\exp(a\exp(a\exp(a\cdots)))$, where $a=\pi/2$, a valid representation of $i$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, tetration

Take $i=e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}}$. For this question it will be more convenient to write it as $i=e^{\frac{\pi}{2}i}$. Substituting in this value for $i$, we get
$$i=e^{\frac{\pi}{2}e^{\frac{\pi}{2}i}}$$
For convenience, let $a=\frac{\pi}{2}$. Repeating this gives us
$$i=e^{ae^{ae^{ae^{\ldots}}}}$$
So, if we apply this substitution infinitely many times, does the $i$ in the end just ... go away? This is a bit confusing because you need an $i$ in there to collapse the whole expression, but things at infinity are weird.

If someone could help me better understand this representation that would be great.

Comment: The issue is that the power tower isn't going to converge: think about starting with $e$ and repeatedly taking it to the $\frac{\pi e}2$ power, it'll just shoot off to infinity.

Comment: Takeaway: The definition of any infinite expression is as a limit of finite expressions. Since all of the finite truncations of the proposed infinite expression are real numbers, their limit will never be $i$ (even if it did exist).

Comment: As a general rule, it's worth being sceptical of these infinite operations. They don't just "automatically work", in the sense that there's always a way to take a binary operation and compose it infinitely many times. Infinite sums have a pretty standard definition, but these kinds of power stacks are less conventional.

Comment: @StephenDonovan, what if instead of a tower with all $a$'s you had $$e^{be^{ae^{ae^{\ldots}}}}$$ instead, where, $b=-3\pi/2$? (I.e., you use $i=e^{-i3\pi/2}$ to start, but then switch to $i=e^{i\pi/2}$ for the rest.) The power tower would then converge to $0$. But, of course, $i\not=0$.

Comment: @BarryCipra Yes, I'm aware that power towers of this type can converge, I was just saying that the proposed one does not converge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can call $$\large{e^{\frac{\pi}{2}e^{\frac{\pi}{2}i}}}$$ a "power tower" of height $2$.

The "power tower"

$$\Large{e^{\frac{\pi}{2}e^{\frac{\pi}{2}e^{\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot^{\cdot^{\cdot^{e^{\frac{\pi}{2}i}}}}}}}}$$

of height $n$ ($n$ iterations) converges to $i$ as $\ n\to\infty\ $ because for each $\ n,\ $ the value of the tower always equals $\ i.$

On the other hand,

$$\Large{e^{\frac{\pi}{2}e^{\frac{\pi}{2}e^{\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot^{\cdot^{\cdot}}}}}}$$

which is different to the power tower limit just discussed, is not equal to a real number.

In general, doing an operation ($\ +, \times,\ $ ^ , other) an infinite amount of times is impossible to do all at once: you must perform the operation a finite amount of times and then let the "number of times" that you perform the operation increase without bound. If the sequence of "partial sums", "partial products" or "partial power towers" tends to a limit as $\ n\to\infty,\ $ then we say the sequence converges as $\ n\to\infty.\ $

See also:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Infinite_heights

Comment: To be fair, none of the power towers discussed equal real numbers. :-P

Comment: Thanks, it seems like the $i$ is necessary then. Would things get more confusing if (instead of $\pi, e$) we had some complex numbers?

Comment: @TheoBendit, see my comment (addressed to Stephen Donovan) below the OP.

Comment: "Would things get more confusing if (instead of π,e) we had some complex numbers?" Probably. If you are going to do that, it might be a good idea to use the modulus-argument form of the complex numbers.